# How to argue that $\int_\epsilon^1 g(t) dt\rightarrow \infty$ for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $$g:(0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad g(t):=\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right\rvert$$

How can I show that $\int_\epsilon^1 g(t) dt\rightarrow \infty$ for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$?

So it is following integral:

$$\int_\epsilon^1 \left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right\rvert\  dt$$

I tried to find a proper inequality for the function, but I did fail. From my intuition I would like to think of the function $|\frac{1}{t}|$, but I do fail to find a right inequality on a specific interval. But maybe there is even a trigonometric equality, which I can apply to $\sin(\frac{1}{t})-\frac{1}{t}\cos(\frac{1}{t})$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The $\sin(1/t)$ becomes irrelevant by the triangle inequality. You are left to compare to $\int_A \frac{c}{t} dt$ where $A=\{ t \in (0,1] : |\cos(1/t)|>c \}$ where $c$ is a convenient constant.

Comment: @Ian Sorry but didn't get how $\sin(1/t)$ became irrelevant by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Me neither. Of course, sinus is just between -1 and 1, but how do I exactly get an inequality, that does treat this irrelevance?

Comment: $|\sin(1/t) - (1/t) \cos(1/t)| \geq (1/t) |\cos(1/t)|-1$. So if the RHS is not integrable then the LHS isn't either. Of course if you wanted to go the other way then you would have $|\sin(1/t) - (1/t) \cos(1/t)| \leq (1/t) |\cos(1/t)|+1$. So indeed you can conclude that the integrability of your function and $(1/t) |\cos(1/t)|$ are the same, even before you know what they are, because their difference is an integrable function.

Comment: Ok, in the case the sinus part is bigger than the cos part you take 0, and in the other case you just lower it even more. Thank you.

Comment: It's not actually as complicated as that, the point is that we showed $||\sin(1/t) - (1/t) \cos(1/t)|-|(1/t) \cos(1/t)|| \leq 1$, that is, the difference between the two is bounded and thus integrable. So they are either both integrable or neither is integrable, so you can continue to analyze just the cos part.

Comment: But why is the set $A$ big enough? I do not see that, yet...

Comment: Choose $c$ to be say $1/\sqrt{2}$, then what you are looking at are basically $\frac{1}{t} \in \pi k \pm \pi/4$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so $t \in \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{k \pm 1/4}$, and on each of these intervals the integrand is basically behaving as $\frac{1}{t}$, so on each of them the integral is basically $k$ times the length of the interval and the length of the interval is basically $\frac{1}{k^2}$. Now just iron out the details.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi}}^1 \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-t\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|dt =\int_{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi}}^1 \left|\left(t\sin \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)'\right|dt =V_{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi}}^1 \left(t\sin \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\geq \left| \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi}\cdot 1 -\frac{1}{n \pi\cdot }\cdot0\right|+\left| \frac{1}{n \pi\cdot }\cdot0 -\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +(n-1)\pi}\cdot 1 \right|+...+\left| \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +\pi} \cdot 1 -\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot 0\right|\to \infty$$
as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\sin\left(\frac1t\right)\right|,\left|\cos\left(\frac1t\right)\right|\le1$$
so:
$$-\frac1t\le\frac1t\cos\frac1t\le\frac1t$$
if we combine this with $\sin$ we get:
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac1t\right)-\frac1t\cos\left(\frac1t\right)\right|\approx\left|1-\frac1t\right|$$
which as $t\to0$ asymptotes to $\frac1t$
so by comparison test we can say:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac1t\,dt$$

Comment: That's not valid at all.